# Heroku application Error Log/gunicorn/django

Tags: python, django, heroku, gunicorn

I am trying to run my django web application on heroku.

The below is my Folder Structure:

```
myblog/
   myblog/
     ...
     wsgi.py
   Procfile
   requirements.txt 
   runtime.txt
   ...
```

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn myblog.wsgi:application --log-file =-
```

Log:

```
2020-02-01T05:24:18.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user myusername@gmail.com
2020-02-01T05:24:53.555023+00:00 app[api]: Deploy f80dc625 by user myusername@gmail.com
2020-02-01T05:24:53.555023+00:00 app[api]: Release v15 created by user myusername@gmail.com
2020-02-01T05:24:54.464684+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-02-01T05:24:58.015753+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn myblog.wsgi:application --log-file =-`
 2020-02-01T05:24:59.499501+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-02-01T05:24:59.502671+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-02-01T05:24:59.481315+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2020-02-01T05:25:03.393607+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn 
myblog.wsgi:application --log-file =-`
2020-02-01T05:25:03.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-02-01T05:25:05.386497+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-02-01T05:25:05.370403+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2020-02-01T05:25:15.342838+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET 
path="/" host=cryptic-peak-88710.herokuapp.com request_id=40f22193-b420-48c8-a79b-d037e97e9c8b 
fwd="211.229.239.157" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
 2020-02-01T05:25:16.518964+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET 
 path="/favicon.ico" host=cryptic-peak-88710.herokuapp.com request_id=10407ff6-814b-4a34-9fd6- 
31e33e90f0e6 fwd="211.229.239.157" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I have tried

```
web: gunicorn project.wsgi:application --preload --workers 1
web: gunicorn project.wsgi:application --log-file=-
```

Please help me find a way to run my application on heroku.

Comment: There's also gunicorn included in requirements.txt

Comment: try `web: gunicorn project.wsgi --log-file -` without mentioning application

Comment: Sadly, getting rid of application didn't work for me..

Comment: try ```web: gunicorn your_project_name.wsgi --log-file - ``` like @MohitChandel suggested and remove the ```=``` sign.  Your code says ```--log-file=- ```